# Memory usage caused by String references in Groovy closures

Tags: groovy

I used groovy to write a crawler DSL that uses a single-threaded event loop to simulate concurrent execution. However, when using this DSL, I found that the memory usage of the program is abnormally high. It should not cost 1.7G of memory for this program. I used jprofiler to analyze the runtime heap memory and found that a large number of char[] and String object instances were created in the following code snippet:

```
reqs = []
domains = ['xxx']
baseUrl = 'https://xxxx' 
spider {

    generateRequest {
        this.reqs.clear()
        if (this.domains != null && this.domains.size() > 0) {
            this.reqs.add(new HttpGet("${this.baseUrl}${this.domains.get(0)}"))
        }
        return this.reqs
    }
```

At first I thought it was a problem with GString delay generating strings,so I modified this code:

```
reqs = []
url = 'https://xxxx'
spider {

    generateRequest {
        this.reqs.clear()
        if (this.domains != null && this.domains.size() > 0) {
            this.reqs.add(new HttpGet(this.url))
        }
        return this.reqs
    }
```

But it doesn't work, but it makes memory usage grow faster. I just started using groovy, is there a problem with my use of groovy closures?
[jprofiler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEzp2.png)

Comment: There is nothing special memory consuming in part of your code. I think problem somewhere else.

Comment: Groovier: `this.domains != null && this.domains.size() > 0` can be reduced to `this?.domains`